# Host key verification failed in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have the following shell script, which is to install puppet agent in a remote machine. It worked perfectly if I run from my local ubuntu by cmd line as such: **sh install_puppet_agent.sh**

```
me@me:~$ cat install_puppet_agent.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo "Installing ..."
ssh -t me@puppet-agent << 'INSTALL_PUPPET_AGENT'

wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppet6-release-bionic.deb
echo "mepassword" | sudo -S dpkg -i puppet6-release-bionic.deb

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install -y puppet-agent
sudo touch /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf
sudo chmod 777 /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf
echo "[main]" | sudo tee -a /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf
echo "certname = puppetagent" | sudo tee -a /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf
echo "server = puppet" | sudo tee -a /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf
echo "environment = production" | sudo tee -a /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf
echo "runinterval = 5m" | sudo tee -a /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf
sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet resource service puppet ensure=running enable=true

INSTALL_PUPPET_AGENT

echo "done"

me@me:~$
```

The I created a simple execute shell job in jenkins by copying the content of install_puppet_agent.sh to the Build -> Execute shell area, then I clicked save/build now, I got this:

```
Installing ...
Host key verification failed.
done
```

I have googled a while, unable to figure it out. I need to confess I am new to Jenkins & Puppet. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is not a security problem that you are facing, you should be ok with updating the content of `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file on the Jenkins node the job executes on.

Examples how to do that:

https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-fix-the-error-host-key-verification-failed/

Answer (score 0):

I got around this issue simply by configure the jenkins job as such:

```
/home/me/install_puppet_agent.sh
```